# Independence of a random variable and a Sigma-algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, independence

This is a proof from Rene Schilling's Brownian Motion that the completion of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the BM $(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is admissible, i.e. the filtration at $s$ is independent of $B_t - B_s$ for all $s<t$.

The proof shows that $E(1_F \cdot (B_u-B_t)) = P(F)E(B_u - B_t)$ for all $F$ in the completion. How does this give independence?

What this seems to show is that a random variable $X$ is independent of a sigma-algebra $\mathscr{G}$ if $E(1_F \cdot X) = P(F) E(X)$ for all $F \in \mathscr{G}$, i.e. $E[X|\mathscr{G}] = E[X]$. But I know that this does not necessarily imply independence. So why is this proof complete?

[image]

Comment: You're right. However, the proof can be saved if one replaces $B_u-B_t$ with $f(B_i-B_t)$, where $f\in \mathcal{C}_b$.